# Python String unwanted overwrite

Tags: python, string, insert

I cant seem to figure out why or how i am loosing characters when manipulating a string in python.

The string is:  `0039-7806RRVLAK`

Expected Output: `0039-7806R-RVLAK`

Actual Output: `0039-7806-RVLAK`

Code:

```
if temp2[4] == '-' and temp2[10] != '-':
     temp3 = temp2[:9] + '-' + temp2[10:]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the 9 to a 10:

```
if temp2[4] == '-' and temp2[10] != '-':
     temp3 = temp2[:10] + '-' + temp2[10:]
```

When you call a string its `str[from:to]`, so `temp2[:9]` is equivalent to `temp2[0:9]` and it would only return the characters from 0-9 instead of the required 0-10